# Node.js - Mocha done() method causing errors in previous tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, chai

I'm implementing Mocha as my testing framework with Chai for an app I'm writing in Node.js.
This spec is written for `secureId.js`.

```
// secureId.js
"use strict"

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Constructor for SecureID
function SecureID(str, rounds, func) {
  // Makes salt and hash unable to be changed or viewed outside the member functions
  let hashedID;
  let gennedSalt;

  bcrypt.genSalt(rounds, (err, salt) => {
    gennedSalt = salt;

    bcrypt.hash(str, salt, (err, hash) => {
        hashedID = hash;
        func(err, salt, hash);
    });
  });

  // Gets the salt associated with the instance
  this.getSalt = function() {
    return gennedSalt;
  };

  // Gets the hash associated with the instance
  this.getHash = function() {
    return hashedID;
  };

  // Set new id for already instantiated SecureID
  this.setNewId = function(str, rounds, func) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(rounds, function(err, salt) {
      gennedSalt = salt;

      if (err)
        func(err);

      bcrypt.hash(str, salt, function(err, hash) {
        hashedID = hash;
        func(err, salt, hash);
      });
    });
  };

  // set new id for already instantiated SecureID synchronously
  this.setNewIdSync = function(str, rounds) {
    gennedSalt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(rounds);
    hashedID = bcrypt.hashSync(str, gennedSalt);
  };

  // Compares a string and hash
  this.equals = function(str, func) {
    bcrypt.compare(str, hashedID, function(err, res) {
      func(err, res);
    });
  };

  // Compares a string and hash synchronously
  this.equalsSync = function(str) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(str, hashedID);
  };
};

exports.SecureID = SecureID;
```

Here is the spec.

```
"use strict";

let expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('SecureID', () => {
  let ids = [];
  let anID = 'aLongIDofCharacters';
  let anAmountOfRounds = 10;
  let SecureID = require('../secureId').SecureID;

  console.log(`Tests with rounds >= 20 will take over an hour to complete. You are doing ${anAmountOfRounds} round(s).`);

  describe('#SecureID()', () => {
    let i = 0;
    let checkingFunction = (done) => {
      if (i == 2) {
        clearInterval(checkingFunction);
        done();
      };
    };

    it('Create an ID', (done) => {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
        ids.push(new SecureID(anID, anAmountOfRounds, (err, salt, hash) => {
          expect(err).to.be.undefined;
          expect(salt).not.to.be.undefined;
          expect(hash).not.to.be.undefined;
          i++;
        }));
      };

      setInterval(checkingFunction, 100, done);
    });
  });

  describe('#getHash()', () => {
    it('Returns a hash.', () => {
      expect(ids[0].getHash()).not.to.be.undefined;
      expect(ids[1].getHash()).not.to.be.undefined;
    });

    it('Returns a hash unique to that generated from the same ID.', () => {
      expect(ids[0].getHash()).not.to.equal(ids[1].getHash());
    });
  });

  describe('#getSalt()', () => {
    it('Returns a salt.', () => {
      expect(ids[0].getSalt()).not.to.be.undefined;
      expect(ids[1].getSalt()).not.to.be.undefined;
    });

    it('Returns a salt unique to that generated from the same ID.', () => {
      expect(ids[1].getSalt()).not.to.equal(ids[0].getSalt());
    });
  });

  describe('#setNewId()', () => {
    let i = 0;
    let checkingFunction = (done) => {
      if (i == 2) {
        clearInterval(checkingFunction);
        done();
      };
    };

    it('Sets a new ID asynchronously.', (done) => {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
        ids[j].setNewId(anID, (err, salt, hash) => {
          let previousHash = ids[j].getHash();
          let previousSalt = ids[j].getSalt();

          expect(err).to.be.undefined;
          expect(salt).not.to.equal(previousSalt);
          expect(hash).not.to.equal(previousHash);
          i++;
        });
      };

      setInterval(checkingFunction, 100, done);
    });
  });

  describe('#setNewIdSync()', () => {
    it('Sets a new ID synchronously.', () => {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
        let previousHash = ids[j].getHash();
        let previousSalt = ids[j].getSalt();

        ids[j].setNewIdSync(anID);

        expect(ids[j].getSalt()).not.to.equal(previousSalt);
        expect(ids[j].getHash()).not.to.equal(previousHash);
      };
    });
  });

  describe('#equals()', () => {
    it('Compares an ID with a hash, calling a callback with the result of genHash(ID) == hash.', () => {
      it('Hash is not equal to an empty string.', (done) => {
        ids[0].equals('', (err, res) => {
          expect(res).to.equal(false);
          expect(err).to.be.undefined;
          done();
        });
      });

      it('Hash is equal to original ID.', (done) => {
        ids[0].equals(anID, (err, res) => {
          expect(res).to.equal(true);
          expect(err).to.be.undefined;
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });

  describe('#equalsSync()', () => {
    it('Compares an ID with a hash, returning the result of genHash(ID) == hash (synchronous).', () => {
      it('Hash is not equal to an empty string.', () => {
        expect(ids[0].equalsSync('')).to.equal(false);
      });

      it('Hash is equal to original ID.', () => {
        expect(ids[0].equalsSync(anID)).to.equal(true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

My problem is that when I reach `#setNewId()`, I am given the following reason for the test failing: `done() called multiple times`. I understand what this error means, but I what I don't understand is that when Mocha outputs the test results, when it gets to `#setNewId()`, it shows

```
1) Create an ID
✓ Sets a new ID asynchronously. (107 ms)
```

Likewise, `#setNewIdSync()` produces the multiple calls to done error, but it seems that is tries to validate `#setNewId()`; its results in Mocha are

```
✓ Sets a new ID synchronously. (252 ms)
2) Sets a new ID asynchronously.
```

Any help? Am I just doing something stupid?

Comment: what's happening with `let checkingFunction = (done) => {` ? im not familiar with chai but it looks to me like `done` is undefined at this point, and even if its just a function argument, the setInterval will call it repeatedly. I don't know why the behavior is as described

Comment: `done` is undefined at that point, but when I call `setInterval(... , ... , done)`, the current `it`'s `done()` is passed to `checkingFunction()`, and since `checkingFunction()` is written to only call `done()` when `i == 2` (which basically just means once both async functions have completed in that block), it should only be calling `done()` once per `it` block.

Comment: Gotcha. I have no further ideas, sorry, other than take a look at [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async) which is really fantastic for simplifying these kinds of complicated async logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I was doing something stupid. It was merely a matter of clearing the interval incorrectly.

This previous code...

```
describe('#SecureID()', () => {
  let i = 0;
  let checkingFunction = (done) => {
    if (i == 2) {
      clearInterval(checkingFunction);
      done();
    };
  };

  it('Create an ID', (done) => {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
      ids.push(new SecureID(anID, anAmountOfRounds, (err, salt, hash) => {
        expect(err).to.be.undefined;
        expect(salt).not.to.be.undefined;
        expect(hash).not.to.be.undefined;
        i++;
      }));
    };

    setInterval(checkingFunction, 100, done);
  });
});
```

attempts to clear the interval `checkingFunction` when it does not exist. The call `setInterval(checkingFunction, ...)` will set the interval with the `checkingFunction` method, however, said interval doesn't exist with the name `checkingFunction`. So, the fix is actually simple:

```
describe('#setNewId()', () => {
  it('Sets a new ID asynchronously.', (done) => {
    let i = 0;
    let checkingInterval = setInterval( () => {
        if (i == 2) {
          clearInterval(checkingInterval);
          done();
        };
      }, 100);

    for (let j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
      ids.push(new SecureID(anID, anAmountOfRounds, (err, salt, hash) => {
        expect(err).to.be.undefined;
        expect(salt).not.to.be.undefined;
        expect(hash).not.to.be.undefined;
        i++;
      }));
    };
  });
});
```

The line `let checkingInterval = setInterval( () => {` creates a new interval called `checkingInterval` that is later cleared inside itself when the async tests have completed.